# React TypeScript: TS Error when using useReducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, definitelytyped

Here is my code:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [count, increase] = useReducer(v => v + 1, 0);
  const handleClick = useCallback(
    () => {
      // TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
      increase();
    },
    []
  );
  return <>{count}<button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button></>;
}
```

Is this some bug in `@types/react`?

I think it should be:

```
type Dispatch<A> = (value?: A) => void;
```

instead of

```
type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;
```

Comment: Yes, the ? Indicate that it can be called without  argument

Answer (score 3):

A dispatch function always needs an action, which should be your second parameter in your reducer:

```
const [count, increase] = useReducer((v, action) => v + 1, 0);
```

The reason being so you can switch over `action.type` and handle each case accordingly. For example:

```
const [count, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return state + 1;
    case 'decrement':
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}, 0);
```

And then you call it like:

```
dispatch({ type: 'increment' });
```

That's why dispatch requires one argument. More information: [Hooks API Reference (useReducer)](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

For your case I suggest using a `useState` instead:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const increase = () => {
  setCount(prev => prev + 1);
}
```

Comment: `useState` is not good enough because increase will change every time it renders.

Comment: `useReducer` doesn't have more functionality, it just makes complex use cases of `useState` easier to reason about. In their cores they are both the same. What do you want to achieve? Just increment the number by 1 every time you click the button? Check out my example using `useState`.